# PHP SELECT query giving wrong primary key result

Tags: php, select

I have a table which contains `cNumber` as primary key which contains data in this format `12-43245` or `12-34537`.

But when select gives out the result, it actually subtracts the value and returns this `-43233` and `-34525` respectively.

Is there any way to get the same value returned and not the subtracted value?

Here is the code
datayupe for cNumber is varchar

```
     $query = "SELECT 'cNumber','cNature','cStNum','cAddress','cTime','cDate','cLocation','cDsp' FROM cases";
          $result=mysql_query($query);
 while($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $id=$row["cNumber"];
echo ($id);
}
```

Checked something. The `$id` value is printed correctly, but when I am using this `$id` in another `INSERT` query, then it inserts the subtracted value in the database

Comment: Can you show the query/code you're using?

Comment: Write the select query you are running

Comment: Please provide the code you're using

Comment: Do you insert it into database like "12-43245" or 12-43245? Is your primary key varchar?

Comment: Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Checked something. The $id value is printed correctly, but when I am using this $id in another INSERT query, then it inserts the subtracted value in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the primary key is integer and not characters so when you do a select it does

```
12-43245 = -43233 and 12-34537 = -34525.
```

If you want to have both digits and special characters try changing the column type to varchar or char.

try to store the id as

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($row["cNumber"]);
```

Comment: It's datatype is varchar...and updated the query in the question.

Comment: I think u want details only where cNum = 12-43245 .So your code will be  "SELECT 'cNumber','cNature','cStNum','cAddress','cTime','cDate','cLocation','cDsp' FROM cases WHERE cNum="'12-43245'"";

Comment: I want to store the "cNumber" value in a array and use that for something else but it subtracts the value and stores.

Comment: I just tried you code and it displays the id without subtracting.Try changing the code to "SELECT cNumber,cNature,cStNum,cAddress,cTime,cDat,cLocation,cDsp FROM cases

Comment: Checked that now. $id=$row["cNumber"] value is printed correctly. But when I use $id in another INSERT query it stores the subtracted value in the databse.

Comment: try to store the id as  
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($row["cNumber"]);

Comment: Try to do insert like this 
$id = mysql_real_string_escape($row["cNumber"]);
'INSERT into cases(cNumber,cNature) VALUES ("'.$id.'","test")'.for simplicity i assume the table cases has 2 columns

Answer (score 2):

I think the primary key is integer and not varchar due to which we the subtract occurs.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't do anything with your data. MySQL doesn't do anything with your data **when you selecting it** too.

So the most likely case - you have this data in your database.

The problem in that case is in insert queries - when you insert row you should insert primary key as string, not as integer.

Comment: I am not using the insert query. Using a .csv file and import into MySQL via phpmyadmin

Comment: Does phpmyadmin shows values of your primary keys as negative integers or as strings?

Comment: strings. I checked something now. The $id=$row["cNumber"] value is printed correctly. But when I use $id in another INSERT query it stores the subtracted value in the databse.